# User input to change time of notification

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, alarmmanager

I am writing a app, one of the features is that it delivers a notification at a set time. That time being 7am. Recently however I wanted to add a notification customize menu, Allowing you to change the time that notifications fire.

current code snippet: (Indents are correct in  code, Formatting them correctly here is difficult)

```
        val TTT = sharedPreferences.getInt("noti1", 7)

        val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, TTT)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
        if (calendar.timeInMillis < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        }
        val mIntent = Intent(this, MyReceiver::class.java)

        val mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this, 1, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                )
        val mAlarmManager = this
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
                mAlarmManager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, 1000*60*60*24, mPendingIntent,
                )
```

The variable TTT, is a int and is the time that the notification should fire. It can be selected by the user in another activity and is then saved in shared prefs and got here to be used.

The receiver file is the code that runs the notification.

When the TTT value hasn't been set, or is just set to a integer, It works fine and repeats fine. However when the value is set by the user, It doesn't work at all. No notifications fire, or they occasionally work but still at the default time (7am).

Is there any way to make this code work so that the notification can fire daily, at whatever time the user sets?

All help is appreciated :)

Edit:
Here is how I went about processing the value set by the user.

```
                val dropdown = dialog.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinnyboi)
                val items = arrayOf("5:00", "6:00", "7:00", "8:00", "9:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00")
                val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items)
                dropdown?.adapter = adapter //applys list of items

                val timeAA = sharedPreferences.getString("notifA", "7:00") //gets shared prefs for the spinner

                //I gave up here, converts string value (got from dropdown) to needed int (time) based on the items position
                if (timeAA == "5:00") {
                    val shit = 0
                    dropdown.setSelection(shit)
                    val noti1 = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                    noti1.putInt("noti1", 5)
                    noti1.apply()
                }else if (timeAA == "6:00") {
                    val shit = 1
                    dropdown.setSelection(shit)
                    val noti1 = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                    noti1.putInt("noti1", 6)
                    noti1.apply()

(so on)
```

And here is another process used to save spinner state and save the shared pref.

```
                //gets the position of selected and then saves it
                dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                    override fun onItemSelected(
                        parent: AdapterView<*>,
                        view: View,
                        pos: Int,
                        id: Long
                    ) {
                        val item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)

                        apply.setOnClickListener {
                            val timeA = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                            timeA.putString("notifA", item as String?)
                            timeA.commit()
                        }

                    }

                    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
                })
```

Comment: "*When the TTT value hasn't been set, or is just set to a integer, It works fine and repeats fine. ***However when the value is set by the user***, It doesn't work at all. No notifications fire, or they occasionally work but still at the default time (7am).*" May I know can you share some codes on how you process *the value set by the user*?

Comment: @Enowneb , yes of course I can. I shall upload a sample of it now. I wont upload the whole thing as its very long  because I sort of gave up and hard coded the entire system as didn't know how exactly to go about making a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you provided, there are 2 points worth noticing:

The first thing is when the user has selected an item in the drop down list, and after that has clicked on `apply`, it will set the time String to `notifA` in `SharedPreferences`. However, will it also set the `Int` value `noti1` you are using for the alarm? Because for this piece of code:

```kotlin
if (timeAA == "5:00") {
    ... // Better rename your variable
    val noti1 = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    noti1.putInt("noti1", 5)
    noti1.apply()
} else if (timeAA == "6:00") {
    ... // Better rename your variable
    val noti1 = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    noti1.putInt("noti1", 6)
    noti1.apply()
} ...
```

If you just put it in like `onCreate()`, it will just be triggered when the `Activity` is shown. There will not be any update after the user has chosen a new time String from drop down list and click on `apply`. So, you may have to consider setting `noti1` inside the `OnClickListener` if the above code is not being called.

The second thing is that, assume your `noti1` in `SharedPreferences` is correctly updated through drop down list, will it cancel the previous set alarm and set another alarm with the updated time? You may have to consider calling the function again after the user has selected from the drop down list to reset for an updated alarm.

---

#### Update an alarm

And if you would like to update an alarm with new time, when you are creating the `PendingIntent`, use flag [`FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT):

> Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, the current one should be canceled before generating a new one.

So you should have your `PendingIntent` created like this:

```kotlin
// Change PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE to PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
val mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    this, 1, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
)
```

And then you can call the above code again to update alarm with the new time.

And make sure the second parameter of the function `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` is the same when recreating the alarm.

```java
public static PendingIntent getBroadcast (Context context, 
                int requestCode, 
                Intent intent, 
                int flags)
```

A different `requestCode` will create another alarm event instead.

#### Cancel an alarm

Meanwhile you can also **cancel** the alarm first and create another alarm later if you want to.

And you should make sure you have the variable holding this `PendingIntent`:

```kotlin
val mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    this, 1, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
)
```

And you can call `AlarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent)` to cancel the alarm:

```kotlin
mAlarmManager.cancel(mPendingIntent)
```

Comment: Yes thank you very much, That's a detailed explanation that has helped me a lot! It sets a string value as well as a int as one of those values are used to save the spinner state for when the menu is next opened. Ill make sure the value is set correctly, thank you!  On another note, I agree with the second point. It was something I experimented with as I think the calendar time is only used once to start it, then its done based on the 24 hour repeating alarm manager.  Do you have any idea how I can cancel the first alarm and set a new one? Would a simple if statement work?

Comment: @Joshu, I have added some more brief descriptions on the possible method. Please check if they can help.